# Trocar o valor de células com valor específico de uma coluna do dataframe em python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Eu tenho esse dataframe :

```
    local time         ghi mean
0       2013-01-01 00:00:00 0.0
1       2013-01-01 01:00:00 0.0
2       2013-01-01 02:00:00 -9999
3       2013-01-01 03:00:00 0.0
4       2013-01-01 04:00:00 0.0
..         ...          ...
8754    2016-12-31 18:00:00 427.5
8755    2016-12-31 19:00:00 194.9
8756    2016-12-31 20:00:00 -9999
8757    2016-12-31 21:00:00 237.6
8758    2016-12-31 22:00:00 -9999
8759    2016-12-31 23:00:00 0.0
```

E eu quero substituir todo valor que seja -9999 da coluna "ghi mean" por 0.
De forma que o resultado seja:

```
    local time         ghi mean
0       2013-01-01 00:00:00 0.0
1       2013-01-01 01:00:00 0.0
2       2013-01-01 02:00:00 0
3       2013-01-01 03:00:00 0.0
4       2013-01-01 04:00:00 0.0
..         ...          ...
8754    2016-12-31 18:00:00 427.5
8755    2016-12-31 19:00:00 194.9
8756    2016-12-31 20:00:00 0
8757    2016-12-31 21:00:00 237.6
8758    2016-12-31 22:00:00 0
8759    2016-12-31 23:00:00 0.0
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o `.loc` para isso. Veja a documentacão [aqui](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df.loc[df['ghi mean'] == -9999, 'ghi mean'] = 0
```

Comment: Valeu amigo, era isso mesmo que eu precisava. Tinha esquecido como aplicar esse comando para esta situação.